# How to get user information from wso2 is 5.x using "oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid"

Tags: oauth, wso2, single-sign-on, openid, wso2-identity-server

I have used WSO2 Identity server 5.2.0 to implement oauth2 authorized flow. I have implemented it successfully. I got access token, but when I tried to fetch user information from WSO2 IS with following command:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer 5e122a0e7276cd4f245e1be238002aa4" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 77faba9b-6a2e-d8ba-a3f6-25ff0da69979" "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid"
```

gives response:

```
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super"}
```

But I need email, first name, last name, role, mobile no etc.

have done configuration suggested in : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+OpenID+Connect+Authorization+Server

I followed: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4250

with https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/pull/1688/
but I don`t understand how to use that build solution after building https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity project.
I have tried with WSO2 Identity server 5.1.0 also but got same response
 Please give any suggetion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IS 5.2.0 used WSO2 carbon oauth v5.1.3 features. So what you have to do is

- Checkout the source for that component tag from [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/tree/v5.1.3).
- Apply the fix mentioned in the ticket on top of that tag.
- Build the source with maven and get the oauth.war file.
- Then replace the "repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth.war" with the new one.
- Remove the "repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2" directory.

Just for the safe side, back up the existing ones before you delete.